# Check if HDD is spinning or in sleep

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

How can I check if HDD(not system of course, but mounted) is spinning or not under Ubuntu 10 Desktop? In some way that not to wake it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `hdparm`.

```
-C     Check  the current IDE power mode status, which will always be one of unknown 
       (drive does not support this command), active/idle (normal operation), standby
       (low  power  mode,  drive  has spun  down), or sleeping (lowest power mode, 
       drive is completely shut down).  The -S, -y, -Y, and -Z options can be used to
       manipulate the IDE power modes.
```

Something like

```
sudo hdparm -C /dev/sdb
```