# Manually controlling hdd sleep

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8.1, sleep, hibernate

My question is about controlling and getting info about HDD sleep (or HDD hibernation) in Windows 8.1. I am not referring to system hybernation.

1. How to manually put hdd into sleep
2. How to check, if hdd is actually sleeping (in a way that doesn't wake it)
3. What is the simplest/nicest way to wake it up from sleep

There is very similar question for ubuntu: [Check if HDD is spinning or in sleep](https://superuser.com/questions/262752/check-if-hdd-is-spinning-or-in-sleep).

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/886399/windows-8-1-puting-hard-drive-into-sleep-mode   System hibernation is a completely different thing, sleep stand-by or spin-down is what you seem to be referring to.  Any user initiated activity trying to see files or run a program from or files from a drive will wake it back up.   The best way to tell if it did sleep it actually to reawaken it , because it will be slow to respond until awakened. many things will knock it out of sleep easily, prevention of that might be best done by "what is on it"

Comment: @Psycogeek In some environments the hdd sleep is also called "hdd hibernation". On the other side I agree that in windows it's "hdd sleep". I understand that system hibernation is different thing and I am reffering to hdd-sleep. Please put your answer in a post instead of comment.

Comment: changed terms for clarity